# SSL on a Website Engine hosting 1000 domains

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

Google is creating a bigger and bigger push to get all websites hosted securely over SSL and using "scare tactics" such as highlighting to the customer that the site is "Not Secure". I'm sure that they'll eventually grow the weighting of a secure site in their rankings.

My technical issue is that I have a website engine hosted as a single site in IIS as part of an Azure Cloud Service.

I have 1,000 or so different domain names (not sub-domains) pointing at the website and the engine determines which site to display to the customer. It all works very well.

However, getting an SSL certificate which copes with 1,000 domains is currently not available (to my knowledge the most is 250), so I'm trying to find a way to get around this.

I've had a few ideas on how to do this, but none seem ideal. Another factor to consider is that sites can come and go - so the regeneration of SSL certificates is going to be required at reasonably regular intervals.

Has anyone dealt with something similar to this before or have any ingenious ideas on a direction I may be able to take and investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

Add too many subject alternative names and you will get browser compatibility problems, if not hit limitations with the underlying cert store. [Nick Craver says the limit is ~100](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#certificates-child-metas-metastackexchangecom), and given this is based on Stack Overflow https I am inclined to believe this.

If you abandon platform as a service and run your own IIS, you can use Centralized SSL Certificate Support with a cert per site, as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks John. I had been researching this and the more domains there are the more data has to be sent through the SSL connection, so most do stop at 100.

I hadn't used Centralized SSL Certificates before and will have a think about if that could be used as an option.